# How I can start Iteration from 1 Using Object.entries() method JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
const game = {
  team1: 'Bayern Munich',
  team2: 'Borrussia Dortmund',
  players: [
    [
      'Neuer',
      'Pavard',
      'Martinez',
      'Alaba',
      'Davies',
      'Kimmich',
      'Goretzka',
      'Coman',
      'Muller',
      'Gnarby',
      'Lewandowski',
    ],
    [
      'Burki',
      'Schulz',
      'Hummels',
      'Akanji',
      'Hakimi',
      'Weigl',
      'Witsel',
      'Hazard',
      'Brandt',
      'Sancho',
      'Gotze',
    ],
  ],
  score: '4:0',
  scored: ['Lewandowski', 'Gnarby', 'Lewandowski', 'Hummels'],
  date: 'Nov 9th, 2037',
  odds: {
    team1: 1.33,
    x: 3.25,
    team2: 6.5,
  },
};
```

**1) Loop over the game.scored array and print each player name to the console,along with the goal number start from 1 like (Goal 1: etc)**

**This is my first solution and the result is perfect:**

```
for (const [i, v] of game.scored.entries()) 
{
  console.log(`Goal: ${i + 1} ${v}`);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Goal: 1 Lewandowski

Goal: 2 Gnarby

Goal: 3 Lewandowski

Goal: 4 Hummels
```

**Picture Result:**
[image]

**The issue is when I tried from different method using Object.entries() the itration don't start from 1**

**Soultion 2**

```
for (const [i, v] of Object.entries(game.scored)) 
{
  console.log(`Goal: ${i+1} ${v}`);
}
```

Output:

```
Goal: 01 Lewandowski

Goal: 11 Gnarby

Goal: 21 Lewandowski

Goal: 31 Hummels
```

**Picture Result:**
[image]

Comment: You can use `${parseInt(i)+1}`

Comment: Finally, I got my answer:
In the **array**, we use the entries method but in the **object**, we have to use the object.entries() method and then pass into the function, the object that we are interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`game.scored.entries()` returns an iterator object in which the indexes are returned as numbers. So adding 1 to the value of `i` performs the addition and gives you the expected result.

`Object.entries(game.scored)` returns the `key` as a string. So when you do `i + 1` in the second code example, instead of doing an addition, your code performs concatenation. Since `i` is a string, 1 will be converted to string and then concatenated with the value of `i`.

To get the desired result, convert `i` to a number before adding 1 to it.

There are multiple ways to convert a string to a number. You can use one of the following ways:

- Using `+` unary operator

  ```
  for (const [i, v] of Object.entries(game.scored)) 
  {
    console.log(`Goal: ${(+i)+1} ${v}`);
  }
  ```
- Using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function

  ```
  for (const [i, v] of Object.entries(game.scored)) 
  {
    console.log(`Goal: ${parseInt(i) + 1} ${v}`);
  }
  ```
- Using [`Number() constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number)

  ```
  for (const [i, v] of Object.entries(game.scored)) 
  {
    console.log(`Goal: ${Number(i) + 1} ${v}`);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The first approach takes the array and its entries ([`Array#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries)), whereas the second one takes the object and the entries from the object ([`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)).

Objects has only strings or symbols as keys. To take a number as value you need to convert it to a number. The shortest way is to take an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).

```js
const
    game = { team1: 'Bayern Munich', team2: 'Borrussia Dortmund', players: [['Neuer', 'Pavard', 'Martinez', 'Alaba', 'Davies', 'Kimmich', 'Goretzka', 'Coman', 'Muller', 'Gnarby', 'Lewandowski'], ['Burki', 'Schulz', 'Hummels', 'Akanji', 'Hakimi', 'Weigl', 'Witsel', 'Hazard', 'Brandt', 'Sancho', 'Gotze']], score: '4:0', scored: ['Lewandowski', 'Gnarby', 'Lewandowski', 'Hummels'], date: 'Nov 9th, 2037', odds: { team1: 1.33, x: 3.25, team2: 6.5 } };


for (const [i, v] of Object.entries(game.scored)) {
    console.log(`Goal: ${+i + 1} ${v}`);
}
```